# ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data in Toad Used by Tab for tables

Tags: oracle, loops, hierarchical-data, toad, connect-by

As you know in Toad, we can see where a table is used (in a package or in a view).
But when I try to see where my table is used it is showing the error :**ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data.**
Other tables are showing up their used status nicely.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: So there's something odd about this particular table. Is it definitely a table and not (say) a synonym? Query ALL_OBJECTS for it.

Comment: @APC certainly it is a table.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use ALL_SOURCE to check where your table has been referred in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but just in case someone comes across it when they need it......

A Connect By loop is always caused by a parent/child relationship. The problem is, the child is installed on its parent, and it's parent is installed on the child. Hence the loop.

I only know this now because I spent all day trying to FIND the bloody looping record. A half-dozen scripts later - I found one that worked! It turned out it was so difficult to find because it was an item installed on ITSELF. HOW our app users managed that...